# Parallelizing file name similarity comparison

Tags: c++, openmp, similarity

Starting with the C++ code provided in http://matpalm.com/resemblance/jaccard_coeff/ I am working to compare file name similarity in a fast way. So far I managed to get "resemblance" code compiling fine here on my Windows 7 (x64) using g++ and -fopenmp switch. Below shows the essential part of the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{

    ofstream file(output_filename_for_thread().c_str());
    int window_finish = number_lines;

    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 1000)
    for(int i=0;i<number_lines;i++) {

        int window_start = i+1;

        // compare each pair output high resemblances
        for (int j=window_start; j<window_finish; j++) {
            if (lines[i][5] == lines[j][5]){ 
            float resemblance = shingles_array[i]->resemblance_to(*shingles_array[j]);
            if (resemblance >= min_resemblance - 0.0001)
                file << lines[i] << "\n"
                     << lines[j] << "\n";
           }
        }
    }

    file.close();
}
```

My biggest change in this code, compared to the original, is to output similar file names instead of the indices and score. In addition, I only intend to compare file names that are starting with the same letter. So here comes the problem definition. This code works fine when I specify 2 threads only, however when I increase the number of threads to 3 or more (upto 8), somehow the program execution prematurely completes without getting any output. What is the way to further debug this problem or better fix it? It would be great if I can get this code working properly for any number of threads. My initial tests show that, this C++ code is about 10 times faster compared to Python version, and at least 2 times faster on a single thread when it is run on 8 processes in Python. Any guidance and comment will be appreciated.

Comment: My simple solution is to move the #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 1000) line on top of the j-loop. Then the program works as expected with the first if-block in and run parallel reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple threads writing to your `file` at the same time.  This results in, at best, a data race and undefined behavior.  You need to synchronize access to `file` or store the results in thread local containers, combine those, and generate the output when the looping is done.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating your suggestion with a small code?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to place the file write operations inside an OpenMP critical section as follows:

```
    // compare each pair output high resemblances
    for (int j=window_start; j<window_finish; j++) {
        if (lines[i][5] == lines[j][5]){ 
        float resemblance = shingles_array[i]->resemblance_to(*shingles_array[j]);
        if (resemblance >= min_resemblance - 0.0001) {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
            file << lines[i] << "\n"
                 << lines[j] << "\n";
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

Be aware that this will introduce a fare amount of synchronization between threads, performance is going to be affected.

Comment: This produces a similar issue as I reported in my original posting, that is the program hangs without completing at all.